# Extracting image from descrption tag of rss feed windowsphone8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I was trying to get image from description tag from many days.Below is the description tag.

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><img hspace="1" height="312" border="1" align="middle" width="300" vspace="3" src="/recipeuserfiles/Katte Pongali-andhra recipes-healthy recipes.PNG" alt="" /></p> <ul> <li>Mix the rice and Green gram dal Cook in pressure cooker and keep it side. </li> <li>Now take a vessel and heat the ghee and add add pepper, cumin seeds, curry leaves and cashew nuts to it. </li> <li>Then add the cokked rice and dal , salt and mix it properly. </li> <li>Delicious pongali is ready to taste. Have it with any of your favorite chutney.</li> </ul>
```

My whole code to parse is

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Recipes
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            // is there network connection available
            if(!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No network connection available!");
                return;
        }
        // start loading RSS-data
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://teluguone.com/recipes/feeds/recipefeeds/rice-4.rss", UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(channelDownloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    }
    string src;
    string desc;


    void channelDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {



            if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
            }
            else
            {
                // Deserialize if download succeeds
                XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Channel));
                Channel channel = (Channel)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
                itemList.ItemsSource = channel.Collection;

             Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(desc);
              if (m.find()) 
             src = m.group(1);
            src="http://www.teluguone.com"+src;
             return src.replaceAll("\\s", "");
            //Log.d("src", src);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I was coming across error 
`Error:'string' does not contain a definition for 'replaceAll' and no extension method 'replaceAll' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

please anybody help me.I was struggling on this from many days and posted in different blogs.I didn't get answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the "content" element to retrieve the HTML and use the regex feature,

```
var reg = new Regex("src=(?:\"|\')?(?<imgSrc>[^>]*[^/].(?:jpg|bmp|gif|png))(?:\"|\')?");
var match=reg.Match(source);
if(match.Success)
{
  var encod = match.Groups["imgSrc"].Value;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I used above code.I was getting errors like Error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex' to 'Recipes.var'. 
Error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Recipes.var'. Error:'Recipes.var' does not contain a definition for 'Groups' and no extension method 'Groups' accepting a first argument of type 'Recipes.var' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Many Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you've included the reference for Regex? using  System.Text.RegularExpressions try adding this with your other namespaces. Or else just go near Regex and hover over the blue squiggly line, it'll automatically add the reference for you.

Comment: Ha yes i was sure i have included reference for Regex.Even though i was comming across the same errors.